# Eclipse mess system and local headers?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, sqlite

I've got pretty strange problem on Eclipse: «'sqlite3' is ambiguous»
for simple declaration: sqlite3 *pDB;
This problem apperas after me was included sqlite3 (builded opensource sqlcipher) version to my project.
Actually it is clear that conflict is between system header (/usr/include/sqlite3.h) and local (project) header sqlite3.h .
So my question is can I avoid this problem by using local version only, for headers and libraries?

In my project I use:

#### #include "sqlite3.h"

it must use local, project header, since header is not in "<...>" but it doesn't.
Is there any good advice?

1. Declaration like #include "./sqlcipher/sqlite3.h" - doesn't work.
2. Declaration with full path to header doesn't help.
3. I know that I can remove sqlite3 dev libs via apt,  but I need for now — other projects.

My build system is: Ubuntu 16 (amd64), clang++, eclipse (Oxygen3a, 4.7.3.a)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the path in your system path variable. Use control panel and set environ variable `path` and add path `./sqlcipher/` at the end of `path` variable (like path=...;C:\some\location\sqlcipher). After that you have to restart your eclipse.